# Scroll in eclipse quick search preview

Tags: eclipse

I'd like to scroll when in the preview part of the quick text search (Search in menu -> Quick Search)
 (IntelliJ has it without any effort). Is it possible?

Comment: In Eclipse the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+L is bound to _Show Key Assist_ by default. What do you mean by _"quick text search"_? If you mean _Find_ (Ctrl+F), check the checkbox _Incremental_.

Comment: edited to clarify what is quick search preview

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. I can not find "quick search" anywhere. Could you add a screenshot of (1) where you trigger the search, and (2) the search preview?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to the search provided by the [Spring Quick Search](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quick-search-eclipse) plug-in.

Scrolling the result preview area vertically is not possible, since the whole point is to open results in the editor.

In case you have many results I recommend using regular Eclipse search, since this search dialog is practically useless.